# Python- delete rows where 2 columns are empty/null

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I need to drop all rows where 2 column values are null (both need to be empty). Code below deletes rows where either one is empty.

```
df.dropna(subset=['name', 'toy'])
```

Code below doesnt delete anything

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', subset=['name', 'toy'])
```

At one point one column was actually empty and other one had NaN. I tried the code after making them both Nan and empty as well.

Comment: `df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', subset=['name', 'toy'])` works for me when the values are actually missing (`NaN` as opposed to `''`). If you need to replace values in the dataframe to be missing instead of empty strings then you can use `df.replace('', np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df.drop(df[pd.isna(df['name']) & pd.isna(df['toy'])].index)
```